# When I try to add the Android SDK to my PATH, it gives a context error

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I'm getting a weird message when my shell reads `.profile`:

```
/Users/alex/.profile:export:69: not valid in this context: SDK/tools:/Applications/Android
```

The error is triggered by this line in my `.zprofile`:

```
emulate sh -c "source .profile"
```

And yet, the following all work:

```
bash .profile
zsh .profile
sh .profile
sh -c "source .profile"
source .profile
```

All return without a problem - no console messages, exit code 0. Here is the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/strugee/dots/blob/445ab28d0ec98e4db4e4c3a1b48100975544ce0c/.profile), and here is the relevant code block:

```
if [ $(uname -s) = "Darwin" ]; then
    # For distributed.net client
    PATH=$PATH:/Applications/dnetc518-macosx-x86
    # For MacPorts
    PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
    # For Fink
    test -r /sw/bin/init.sh && . /sw/bin/init.sh
    # For Android
    PATH=$PATH:"/Applications/Android SDK/tools":"/Applications/Android SDK/platform-tools"
    # For Homebrew formulae on OS X
    export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH

    ##
    # Your previous /Users/alex/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/alex/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-03-16_at_00:07:13
    ##

    # MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-03-16_at_00:07:13: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
    export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
    # Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
fi
# this is line 69. it is blank in the original file.
```

I'm using the `zsh` that comes with OS X 10.9. I haven't gotten a chance to test this on a GNU/Linux box yet, but I don't think that's the problem.

```
% zsh --version
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run under `set -x` to see where the problem lies. Zsh's line number reporting seems to be off inside `emulate -c`.

> ```
> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
> ```

For POSIX compliance, you need double quotes here, because `export` is parsed as an ordinary command. Without quotes, `$PATH` is split into words according to the value of `IFS` and each word is interpreted as a wildcard pattern, as always happens in Bourne-style shells (not including zsh). Bash and ksh treat `export` specially and parse the argument like an assignment, and zsh doesn't do variable splitting unless explicitly told to, but you don't have this luxury in zsh's sh emulation mode or in dash.

You can use any of the following styles:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export "PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:"$PATH"
```

Or you can leave off the `export`. Except on antique pre-POSIX Bourne shells, once a variable is in the environment, assignments change the value in the environment, you don't need to call `export` again. In an assignment, you don't have to use quotes (but you can if you prefer).

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/68748#68748) for more of the fine print of when you can get away without quotes.